# Javascript click event not firing the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application where I get my data from the back-end side and I use a function in JavaScript to set up my click event. My desired output (for now) is to see an alert box with text saying which row index I clicked on.

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
    function OnSelect() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table-list");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler =
            function(row)
            {
              return function () {
                var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                var id = cell.innerHTML;
                $.ajax({
                  type: "post",
                  url: "/Foo/FooSelected",
                  data: { name: id },
                  success: function (data) {
                    alert(data); //works the second time I click
                  }
                });
              };
            };
        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Just for show this is how I am adding the function on my html:

```
<table id="table-list" class="table table-striped table-sm" runat="server">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>My Foo Table</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.FooCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                  <tr onclick="OnSelect()" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <td>@Model.FooCollection[i].FooName</td>
                  </tr>
                }
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

My issue is that I get my alert box after I click on any row a second time. What do I need to do in order to get my alert box to show after just one click? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are calling the OnSelect() function when you click your row, which in turn adds the event handler which shows your alert, until you click the row the first time, it doesn't have the event handler to show the alert, that is why it takes 2 clicks.

Comment: Once your dom is loaded, add your events to your rows, if you are using JQuery, I'd recommend looking into doing this with document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to be using plain javascript here is how I would do it, (place this inside your script tag):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    // Handler when the DOM is fully loaded
     var table = document.getElementById("table-list");
     var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          var currentRow = table.rows[i];


          currentRow.onclick = function(row)
          {
            return function () {
               var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
               var id = cell.innerHTML;
               $.ajax({
               type: "post",
               url: "/Foo/FooSelected",
               data: { name: id },
               success: function (data) {
                   alert(data); //works the second time I click
              }
            });
          };
        };
   }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Just out of curiosity what do I pass onto my row's onClick event?

Comment: You're welcome, and if you mean what do you place in the html on your row elements, just remove the onclick attribute altogether. It is better practice to add events to elements in your script rather than placing them directly into the HTML.

Comment: Glad I could help.